# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Three.js

Tags: three.js

Hello everybody i'm trying to load 3D object in the browser using Three.js framework, and i'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"  this is the error http://s14.postimg.org/ib0coauf5/length_Error.png!, this error occurs when i'm trying to load a complex 3D object  (a table for example), but when it's a simple object (a cube for example) no error is shown and my object is loaded successfully.
and this is the code of my JSonloader           
      `var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
      loader.load( "models/object3d.json", function(geometry){
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
});`
and this this the export options in blender2.73a http://s13.postimg.org/bfluv5nw7/export.png
any help will be verry appreciated thank you!

Comment: You are linking to a version of three.js that is almost 2 years old. Bad idea. Upgrade to the current version and debug with the non-minified version of three.js.

Comment: Try using the non minified version of three.js so you can see the exact line number and code where the error occurs